# Jquery textbox validation is not working for key '%'

Tags: jquery

My requirement is to allow only alphabetic characters, `-`, `'`

But following code is allowing the user to enter `%`.

```
$('.regx').on("keypress", function (event) {
    var englishAlphabet = /[a-zA-Z-']/g;
    var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
    if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || englishAlphabet.test(key)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Please help me to resolve this issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `event.keyCode == 37` (this is the `%` char).

Also:
 
`-` is event.keyCode == 45

`'` is event.keyCode == 39

So... In total, you will stay with:

```
$('.regx').on("keypress", function (event) {
    var englishAlphabet = /[a-zA-Z-']/g;
    var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
    if (event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 45 || englishAlphabet.test(key)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rsdPz/

Comment: @Shay..I tried with this but it also not allowing to enter ' and -.

Comment: Go to the fiddle, for me it is allowing both ' and -

Comment: @Shay..My Bad..after clearing cookies I tested again and now it's working.Thanks!

Comment: @Shay...I am facing one problem in FireFox.Tab and backspace keys are not working with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
if ((event.KeyCode == 53 || event.KeyCode == 101) && event.shiftKey) {
     return false;
}
```

`event.shiftKey` to check `shift` key is pressed

`event.KeyCode == 53` to check `5` is pressed

`event.KeyCode == 101` to check `numpad 5`

combination of both makes `%`

and change event to `keydown`

> `% and left arrow` has key code as 37

---

**Updated after OP's comment**

<kbd>[**Updated Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/dzn4M/6)</kbd>

KeyCode `222` for `'`

KeyCode `189` for `-`

```
$('.regx').on("keydown", function (event) {
    var englishAlphabet = /[a-zA-Z-']/g;
    var key = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
    var KeyCode = event.KeyCode || event.which;
    console.log(KeyCode);
    if ([222, 53, 101, 189].indexOf(KeyCode) > -1 && event.shiftKey) { //add here
        return false;
    }
    if ([8, 37, 222, 189].indexOf(KeyCode) > -1 || englishAlphabet.test(key)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

[Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: @Tushar...I am getting error in console-
Uncaught ReferenceError: Keys is not defined (repeated 7 times)

Comment: @Hitman Check Updated code with working fiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/dzn4M/1

Comment: @Tushar..In fiddle, your code is not allowing to enter ' and -

Comment: @Tushar..Now it is allowing to enter " but my requirement is to allow only alphabetic characters, -, '

Comment: I tried with your code.But it is not allowing to enter " - " in FF.Rest all keys are working fine in both browser.